# zigzag indexing in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, subset

I have a matrix

```
mat <- matrix(rep(c("L","R"),5),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
cols <- c(1,1,2,1,1)
set.seed(42); test <- rnorm(5)
```

and I would like to get

First, one element from each row and the columns ins `cols`, yieldings here:

```
> res
#[1] "L" "L" "R" "L" "L"
```

Second, elements from selected rows, say those for which `test>0`, and the corresponding columns in `cols[test>0]`, yielding here:

```
> res
#[1] "L" "R" "L" "L"
```

Is there some fast way of using `cols` to index `mat`?

Comment: Maybe `diag(mat[,cols])`?

Comment: @Sotos: great solution, the only problem is if `mat` has a lot of rows, because `mat[,cols]` creates a throwaway matrix of size `nrow(mat) x nrow(mat)`

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks. Yes, that is the downside. Maybe I 'll add it with an efficiency warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrix indexing :

```
mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat),cols)][test > 0]
```

From documentation of `?'['` :

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as
>   many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector
>   with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

Comment: I tried with 50k rows and took a split second! Cheers, the `cbind()`really did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of using `cols` to index your matrix can be,

```
diag(mat[,cols])
#[1] "L" "L" "R" "L" "L"

#add the filter,
diag(mat[,cols])[test > 0]
#[1] "L" "R" "L" "L"
```

**NOTE:** As @digEmAll mentions, this will be terribly inefficient if the original matrix has a lot of rows. This is because it creates an `nrow(mat) x nrow(mat)` matrix in order to get the diagonal

Answer (score 1):

```
mat <- matrix(rep(c("L","R"),5),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)                  
cols <- c(1,1,2,1,1)                                                 
set.seed(42); (test <- rnorm(5))                                       
#> [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683
```

Not sure why I get four elements > 0 when you got three. Anyway...

```
sapply(seq_along(1:nrow(mat)), function(i) mat[i, cols[i]])          
#> [1] "L" "L" "R" "L" "L"
sapply(seq_along(1:nrow(mat)), function(i) mat[i, cols[i]])[test > 0]
#> [1] "L" "R" "L" "L"
```

But matrix indexing is quite a bit faster and is *the* answer.

Comment: You were right, accidentally deleted one element but fixed it now. Cheers,